# How can I export the product image URLs?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export

How can I export the product image URLs from Magento 1.9?

I've used the import/export tool in Magento 1.9.
The resulting CSV file contains no product image URLs.

Comment: do you need any php script that export product url ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are excluding the image path field, otherwise that media_image column should be there.

In `System\ImportExport\Export` select just sku and image path as fields to export. See if it works. Then you can go ahead exporting all attributes which can be lengthy.

Comment: In my store 20k products, when i used  System\ImportExport\Export, its return 'no valid data sent report'  how can i trigger  System\ImportExport\Export by command Line.

Comment: i can't see the option

Answer (score 0):

This answer may only be viable for certain cases but you could export out your stores relavent catalog_product_flat_n (n being the store id) table if you have access to it via a PHPmyadmin interface.